# ANDROID IMAGE TRANSLATION

Tags: android, layout

I want to know about the image translation activity.

The layout should contain two images and these two images should 
split towards left and right at the same time when we click a button
one image should translate towards left and the other towards right.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either post code or check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#translate-element) on what you're asking and get a little more descriptive. This isn't a vending machine for code, people generally don't want to just code things for people because they ask for it. What exactly are you having problems with would be a good start? Please read documents, try again and if you can't get it come back with details; you'll find help quicker.

[edit]----tutorial below-----

Since you've actually given some level of detail here I suppose I'll show you a simple method. First, [`this`](http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/) is a great place for animation information. Use it. Second, this code worked perfect for me on the Droid2.

```
public class animationTEST extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    LinearLayout layout;
    LinearLayout layout2;
    Animation movement;
    Animation movement2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get the layouts
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

        // Create animation for right image
        movement = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.animation_test);
        movement.reset();
        movement.setAnimationListener(this);

        // Create animation for left image
        movement2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.animation_test2);
        movement2.reset();
        movement2.setAnimationListener(this);        


        // Start animation on each image
        layout2.startAnimation(movement2);
        layout.startAnimation(movement);}

    // Listen for animations to be finished
    // There are more efficient ways, I'm just being lazy.
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        layout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // or do whatever it is you wanted to do here, like launch another activity?
    } 

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {    
    } 

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { 
    } 

}
```

The `main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Animation Test Activity" />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dip" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dip" android:id="@+id/imageView2"></ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_marginLeft="145dip">

            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dip" android:id="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The `animation_test.xml` (defining translate animation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fromXDelta="0" 
     android:toXDelta="65%p" 
     android:fromYDelta="0"
     android:toYDelta="0%" 
     android:duration="3000" 
     android:zAdjustment="top"/>
```

The `animation_test2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fromXDelta="0" 
     android:toXDelta="-65%p" 
     android:fromYDelta="0"
     android:toYDelta="0%" 
     android:duration="3000" 
     android:zAdjustment="top"/>
```

If you can't understand this, go back and read both documents I've given you. There is enough information here to understand just about any of the animations. However, your wanting to use `animationDrawable` objects isn't right, because that's a frame animation, not a transformation or motion. Frame based animation is simply making something look like it's dancing, or waving. When you're trying to simply move, fade, or scale an image you want transformation animations. Hope this helps!

Comment: hi,  I am a new bie to android ,I mean how can we transit/translate two images towards left and right in a single layout?    I have stored two images in res/drawable, and how can we use drawableanimation functionality,  waiting for the reply

Comment: @user705336 I've since added more information on the topic, I hope it helps your cause. However, in the future read around a little bit so you can provide accurate details about what's wrong and what you need help doing. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much its working for me  and how can we add on touch functionality to this ,I created a button but its not working